# Question about Microsoft Visual Studio intergrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Is there any way to attach debugger to intergrated terminal? Every time I run debugger in VS, it opens cmd windows for me, but I want it to run in intergrated terminal, is it possible to do so?